# Extract text from json response array from api.ai

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialogflow-es

I am trying to built chatbot that fetches json response from api.ai. I need to display messages part from below json response.

```
{
"id": "ae66f8e4-a047-478a-8108-8b0147610f18",
"timestamp": "2017-09-28T05:02:03.552Z",
"lang": "en",
"result": {
"source": "agent",
"resolvedQuery": "hi",
"action": "",
"actionIncomplete": false,
"parameters": {},
"contexts": [],
"metadata": {
  "intentId": "d2f3c8bd-fc1b-4b6b-9d3d-08b6be93364e",
  "webhookUsed": "false",
  "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
  "intentName": "greetings"
},
"fulfillment": {
  "speech": "Hi.Please enter your query.",
  "messages": [
    {
      "type": 0,
      "speech": "Hi.Please enter your query."
    }
  ]
},
"score": 1
},
"status": {
"code": 200,
"errorType": "success"
 },
 "sessionId": "saurabh"
```

}

Below is the sample piece of code, but it is unable to fetch speech from messages part in spokenResponse variable.

```
   function prepareResponse(val) {
  var debugJSON = JSON.stringify(val,undefined, 2);
  var spokenResponse = val.messages.speech;

  respond(spokenResponse);
  debugRespond(debugJSON);

}
```

I get below error:

```
 script.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'speech' of undefined
  at prepareResponse (script.js:33)
  at Object.success (script.js:21)
  at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
  at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
  at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
  at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

However, when I try to fetch source from result part it fetches correctly.

```
var spokenResponse = val.result.source;
```

I am new to ajax and Json, Kindly help.

Comment: ´message´ is a subobject of ´fulfillment´.
So val.fulfillment.message[0].speech should be correct to accces the value.

Comment: `.messages` appears to be an array not an object you're looking for `.messages[0].speech` maybe?

Comment: I tried using var spokenResponse = val.fulfillment.messages[0].speech; still the same error
script.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined

Comment: Try to console.log(val). Do you see the fulfillment property as part of the result?

Comment: var spokenResponse = val.result.fulfillment.messages[0].speech;

This works, LennieCodes you rock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access messages via the fulfillment property. Note that messages contains an array of objects, so in order to get to the speech property of the first object, you have to access the object in the first index.

```
var spokenResponse = val.fulfillment.messages[0].speech;
```

If you wanted to iterate through all messages (assuming you have more than one message):

```
var messageArr = val.fulfillment.messages;
var speechArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < messageArr.length; i++) {
    speechArr.push(messageArr[i].speech);
}
```

This will give you an array of speech messages.

Comment: var spokenResponse = val.fulfillment.messages[0].speech; This also throws same error, I am getting json respose from api.ai through javascript. When I compare json response in api.ai and when fetched through my code it's exactly same, but unable to access messages part. I even tried
var spokenResponse = val.fulfillment.speech; since fulfillment past also has speech, but unable to access

Comment: "Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined" means there is no fulfillment property in the JSON object. Do a console.log(val) inside your function and see what it gives you. Do you see a fulfillment property?

Comment: Thanks for guiding in correct direction, after seeing console.log made below changes and its working.

var spokenResponse = val.result.fulfillment.messages[0].speech;